# php store variable into array

Tags: php

i have many variable want to store into array

```
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

now i want store $value again into array

p.s: look like foolish but it is educational purpose please don't tell why i am doing already $colors array is exits

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) For everyone how wants to know why i marked it as dupe: http://imgur.com/kFwPK8d

Comment: Please read question i have no idea why you mark duplicate

Comment: Because you completely changed your question! Why did you completely changed your question?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
    $value = strtoupper($value);
    $colors[$key] = $value;
}
```